# Overwrite values on exsisting keys in JS

Tags: javascript

Hi I have following objects in an array and they appear like this:

```js
[{col1:abc}
{col2:def}
{col1:ghi}]
```

What I want to do is if the same key is coming again I should overwrite it so it becomes

```js
[{col1:ghi}
{col2:def}]
```

instead of appending another key value pair.

I am thinking of something like to overwrite

```js
[col1:{col1:ghi}
 col2:{col2:def}]
```

so that i can easily iterate over them in future.
Is there any way to put my keys in this way by using map or something similar?

Thank you

Comment: Pl clarify your question. Do you want to overwrite the keys or do you want to map and have all the keys?

Comment: I want to overwrite meaning each key should have only one key value pair

Answer (score 4):

I'm going to assume all your objects look like the ones you provided in your question, i.e. they each are a single key-value pair (like {col1: "abc"})

We first need to loop over all the objects in your array, combining them into one large object. Since an object cannot have two identical keys, this has the effect of overwriting values associated with a key that occur earlier in the array with ones that associate with the same key, but occur later. This can be achieved with:

`const unifiedObj = arr.reduce((acc, obj) => Object.assign(acc, obj), {})`

`reduce` is a way of "looping" over the items in an array (well, not exactly, but you can think of it this way for now). Object.assign is a way to merge two objects. You should look these up in the MDN docs.

So now, if your original array looked like this:

```
[
    {col1:"abc"}
    {col2:"def"}
    {col1:"ghi"}
]
```

The "unified" object will look like this:

```
{
    col1: "ghi",
    col2: "def"
}
```

Next, since you want an array of 'single key-value pair objects' as your final result, instead of this unified object, we're going to have to extract each key-value pair in the unified object into a new object, and collect all those new objects into an array. That's what this statement does.

`const result = Object.keys(unifiedObj).map(k => ({k: unifiedObj[k]}))`

`Object.keys` gives you all the keys of an object as an array. `map` transforms an array into another array, using the function supplied as its argument. Look these up too.

At the end, result will be an array that looks like this:

```
[
    { col1: "ghi" },
    { col2: "def" }
]
```

which seems to be what you wanted. Do note that the objects in the array might be in a different order from what you expect, i.e. the final array may also look like this:

```
[
    { col2: "def" },
    { col1: "ghi" }
]
```

Comment: So how does the OP (or anyone else in the future that reads this question) learn anything from this? You're not explaining a single piece of your answer at all. Next time a simular issue arises, OP will just have to come back and ask again, cause he didn't learn anything. Just a quick fix.

Comment: Great answer @ack_inc! Quick question, could you explain how your code works? Thank you and again, quite impressive :)

Comment: Isn't this solution non-isomorphic? I.e. the structure of the output differs from that of the input.

Comment: I've tested this, and yes, this simply is not what the OP asks for (the output contains modified key names).

Comment: @icecub: You're right. I've added some details that will hopefully aid OP's understanding

Comment: @NurbolAlpysbayev: It seems to me that the OP does *not* want the output to be isomorphic.

Answer (score 2):

This is quite an easy task! The explanation is in the code comments.

```js
const arr = [{col1:'abc'},
{col2:'def'},
{col1:'ghi'}]


arr.forEach((item, index) => {

  // get the key `col1`, `col2` etc. (only works if there is one key in the object!) 
  const key = Object.keys(item)[0]
  
  // now check if the key was previously encountered
  for (i = 0; i < index; i++) {
    if (arr[i][key] !== undefined) {
      // the same key was found in the already processed chunk of the array! Rewrite it with the latter value!
      arr[i][key] = item
      
    }
  }
})

console.log(arr)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you probably want to produce a single object from your array of objects and retain all values for the same key, so that

```
[
  {col1: 'abc'},
  {col2: 'def'},
  {col1: 'ghi'}
]
```

becomes

```
{
  col1: ['abc', 'ghi'],
  col2: ['def']
}
```

if that sounds right, then here's how to do it:

```js
const arr = [
  {col1: 'abc'},
  {col2: 'def'},
  {col1: 'ghi'}
];

const result = arr.reduce((memo, o) => {
  Object.entries(o).forEach(([key, val]) => {
    memo[key] = memo[key] || [];
    memo[key].push(val);
  });
  return memo;
}, {});

console.log(result)
```